# Looping over file, only get one line

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

Say we have a text file with this contents:

```
dogs
cats
bears
trees
fish
rocks
sharks
```

these are just words separated by newline chars. I am trying to create a Node.js addon. The Addon will read through a file and replacing matching lines with a blank line. Say I pass my program a regex that matches `/trees/`. If I pass the file to my C++ program it will read + write to the file, and result in:

```
dogs
cats
bears
   
fish
rocks
sharks
```

Right now, the problem is it's not looping through all the lines in the file. I get the feeling that's opening the file in append mode and therefore just starting at the end of the file? I can't tell. *Anyway, I want to edit the file in place, not truncate and re-write or replace the whole file, because this will interrupt processes which are tailing the file.*

Here's the code:

```
#include <nan.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Method(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New("world").ToLocalChecked());
}

void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {

fstream infile("/home/oleg/dogs.txt");

if(infile.fail()){
  cerr << " infile fail" << endl;
  exit(1);
}

int pos = 0;
string line;

int count = 0;
while (getline(infile, line)){    

// we only seem to loop once, even though the file has 7 or 8 items 

    count++;
    long position = infile.tellp();
    cout << "tellp position is " << position << endl;
    string str(line);
    int len = str.length();

    cout << " => line contains => " << line << endl;
    cout << " line length is " << len << endl;

    std::string s(len, ' ');  // create blank string of certain length

    infile << s;   // write the string to the current position

    pos = pos + len;
    cout << "pos is " << pos << endl;


}


 cout << " => count => " << count << endl;
infile.close();


  exports->Set(Nan::New("hello").ToLocalChecked(),
               Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Method)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(hello, Init)
```

To compile the code you might need to use Node.js tooling, which is

```
node-gyp rebuild
```

I am a C++ beginner and I think this can be figured out without compiling/running the code.

Comment: Unless you have very strong reasons to do otherwise, I would suggest opening the file using an `std::ifstream`, reading the contents of the file line by line, saving the transformed lines in a `std::vector<std::sting>`, closing the file, opening the file again but using an `std::ofstream`, writing the contents of the `std::vector<std::string>`, and then closing the file.

Comment: sure, probably because writing to the file while looping over the contents is always bit risky

Comment: @RSahu but do you have any idea why I am only going through the loop once for a file with multiple lines of text?

Comment: Reading from and writing to the file using the same `ifstream` object has a lot of pitfalls. I don't understand them all to be able to explain to you what could be going wrong in your particular use case.

Comment: @RSahu I will take your advice on not reading and writing in the same iteration but I still am mystified about why it's only reading one line from the file (the last line). It doesn't make any sense, and it was reading the whole file before but now it's not anymore, the file definitely has multiple lines in it.

Comment: I think it might have been that I need std::getLine instead of just getLine

Comment: I don't think so. Using ADL, that call gets resolved to `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question on why you only read one line of the input file:

Your first write to the file likely sets the `eofbit` on the stream, so the second `getline()` attempt will think it has no more to read.

The comment from @RSahu describes the simplest way to do this for text files.

Comment: thanks for that info, the eofbit thing didn't occur to me